# Como alinear los divs en html y css?

Tags: html, css

voy iniciando en frontend y empecé a crear mi primer proyecto personal.
Inicie con el desarrollo de esta interfaz (asi es como quiero que se vea):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y asi es como segun yo hice la division para poder desarollar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esto es lo que he podido hacer:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Llevo bloqueado todo el dia tratando de resolver mi problema y no se a donde recurri, me gustaria recibir feedback, este es el html:

```css
.headerinfo {
  padding-left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.contain er-left {
  display: flex;
  margin: 15px 0px;
}

.headerinfo-cajas {
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-right: 30px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.headerinfo-cajas__titulo {
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.headerinfo-cajas__titulo-center {
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

.headerinfo-cajas__subtitulo {
  color: #796f6a;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.headerinfo-cajas__subtitulo-2 {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.iconos {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.headerinfo-cajas__icon {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
i
<section class="headerinfo">
  <div class="container-left">

    <div class="headerinfo-cajas">
      <h1 class="headerinfo-cajas__titulo">Casa Sofia en El Palomar</h1>
      <p class="headerinfo-cajas__subtitulo">3 personas han ofertado por esta propiedad</p>
      <p class="headerinfo-cajas__subtitulo">El Palomar, Tlajomulco, Jalisco</p>
      <div class="iconos">
        <img class="headerinfo-cajas__icon" src="../maquetacion-principal/assets/star.png" alt="Estrella">
        <img class="headerinfo-cajas__icon" src="../maquetacion-principal/assets/location.png" alt="Ubicacion">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="headerinfo-cajas">
      <h3 class="headerinfo-cajas__titulo-center">$6.0</h3>
      <p class="headerinfo-cajas__subtitulo-2">millones</p>
    </div>

    <div class="headerinfo-cajas">
      <h3 class="headerinfo-cajas__titulo-center">4</h3>
      <p class="headerinfo-cajas__subtitulo-2">hab</p>
    </div>

    <div class="headerinfo-cajas">
      <h3 class="headerinfo-cajas__titulo-center">4</h3>
      <p class="headerinfo-cajas__subtitulo-2">baños</p>
    </div>

    <div class="headerinfo-cajas">
      <h3 class="headerinfo-cajas__titulo-center">945 mt2</h3>
      <p class="headerinfo-cajas__subtitulo-2">$6,349 / mt2</p>
    </div>

  </div>

</section>
```

necesito ayuda en la parte de los flexbox, estoy muy atorado en esa tema, estuve practicando con paginas de ejercicios en css y aun asi no he podido encotrar una solucion, tambien intente hacerlo desde la consola y no se cual es el error que tengo

Comment: El flexbox es un tema difícil de comprender al 100% la primera vez, pero no te desanimes, a mí me ayudó mucho un video curso de FalconMasters, si te interesa le puedes dar un vistazo. Explica con gran calma y muy padre la verdad, con él yo aprendí las bases de todo lo que es front-end :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es el orden en que los estás colocando, es mejor colocar un div que tenga dentro el ícono y el texto. Esto asegura que estén alineados así como que sea más fácil su manejo.

```css
.headerinfo {
        padding-left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .contain er-left {
        display: flex;
        margin: 15px 0px;
    }

    .headerinfo-cajas {
        overflow: hidden;
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        margin-right: 30px;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .headerinfo-cajas__titulo {
        color: black;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    .headerinfo-cajas__titulo-center {
        color: black;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .headerinfo-cajas__subtitulo {
        color: #796f6a;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .headerinfo-cajas__subtitulo-2 {
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .iconos {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .descripcion {
        display: flex;
    }
    .headerinfo-cajas__icon {
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Toggle</title>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="headerinfo">
        <div class="container-left">

            <div class="headerinfo-cajas">
                <h1 class="headerinfo-cajas__titulo">Casa Sofia en El Palomar</h1>
                <div class="iconos">
                    <div class="descripcion">
                        <img class="headerinfo-cajas__icon" src="../maquetacion-principal/assets/star.png" alt="Estrella">
                        <p class="headerinfo-cajas__subtitulo">3 personas han ofertado por esta propiedad</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="descripcion">
                        <img class="headerinfo-cajas__icon" src="../maquetacion-principal/assets/location.png" alt="Ubicacion">
                        <p class="headerinfo-cajas__subtitulo">El Palomar, Tlajomulco, Jalisco</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="headerinfo-cajas">
                <h3 class="headerinfo-cajas__titulo-center">$6.0</h3>
                <p class="headerinfo-cajas__subtitulo-2">millones</p>
            </div>

            <div class="headerinfo-cajas">
                <h3 class="headerinfo-cajas__titulo-center">4</h3>
                <p class="headerinfo-cajas__subtitulo-2">hab</p>
            </div>

            <div class="headerinfo-cajas">
                <h3 class="headerinfo-cajas__titulo-center">4</h3>
                <p class="headerinfo-cajas__subtitulo-2">baños</p>
            </div>

            <div class="headerinfo-cajas">
                <h3 class="headerinfo-cajas__titulo-center">945 mt2</h3>
                <p class="headerinfo-cajas__subtitulo-2">$6,349 / mt2</p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias Eduardo, me funciono, supongo que para el boton que quiero poner de lado derecho tambien tendré que separarlo en un div, cierto? :)

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido,

Parece que el problema principal lo tienes en la forma en que has marcado los elementos en html, concretamente esta parte:

```
<div class="headerinfo-cajas">
    <h1 class="headerinfo-cajas__titulo">Casa Sofia en El Palomar</h1>
    <p class="headerinfo-cajas__subtitulo">3 personas han ofertado por esta propiedad</p>
    <p class="headerinfo-cajas__subtitulo">El Palomar, Tlajomulco, Jalisco</p>
    
    <div class="iconos">
        <img class="headerinfo-cajas__icon" src="../maquetacion-principal/assets/star.png" alt="Estrella">
        <img class="headerinfo-cajas__icon" src="../maquetacion-principal/assets/location.png" alt="Ubicacion">
    </div>
</div>
```

Con esto lo que creas es una caja que contiene cuatro elementos:

- El elemento `<h1>`
- Dos elementos `<p>`
- Un elemento `<div>` (con dos iconos)

Mientras que según tu maqueta, lo que quieres ahí es:

- Un elemento `<h1>`
- Dos elementos `<div>`, cada uno de ellos con un elemento  y un elemento

```
<div>
    <img src="el-icono-estrella" alt="⭐">
    <p>3 personas han hecho ofertas para esta propiedad</p>
</div>
```

En el CSS tienes que hacer ese `<div>` un elemento flex con los elementos en una línea.